# Does a cyclotomic polynomial actually depend on the base field

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

The $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{n,K}(x)$ associated with a field $K$ (with characteristic 0 or coprime with $n$) is $\prod_{1\leq j\leq n, (j,n) = 1}(x - \omega^j)$ where $\omega$ is a generator of the group $\mu_n(L) = \{\alpha \in L: \alpha^n = 1\}$, with $L$ being a splitting field of $x^n - 1 \in K[x]$. Let's note the well-known fact that $\Phi_{n,K} \in K[x]$.

My question is - does the polynomial essentially depend on the field? What I mean is - for example $\Phi_{8,\mathbb{Q}} = x^4 + 1$ but it's looks to me that (for $p$ - odd) $\Phi_{8,\mathbb{F}_p} = x^4 + 1$? There is only the formal difference of the coefficients belonging to $\mathbb{Q}$ in one case and to $\mathbb{F}_p$ in the other. But the polynomials "look the same" - more formally: $\Phi_{8,\mathbb{Q}} \pmod p = \Phi_{8,\mathbb{F}_p}$. Is this true for all $n$ and why?

Comment: $\Phi_n(x) =\prod_{d | n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(d)}$ is well-defined over any polynomial ring. Its factorization over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ and $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p ,p\nmid n$ is clear. The remaining case is $n= mp^k$ where you'd use $x^{mp^k}-1 \equiv (x^m-1)^{p^k} \bmod p$. The next step is to relate the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n] = \Bbb{Z}[x]/(\Phi_n(x))$ with surjective morphisms $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n] \to \Bbb{F}_p(\omega_n)$.